# How to find CFBundleRef from a function address or a class

Tags: c++, c, macos, macos-carbon, core-foundation

Is it possible to get the Bundle reference (CFBundleRef) from a function address or a class name in Carbon..??

I know there are functions in Objective-C

```
NSBundle myBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:(Class)<SOME_CLASS>];
```

and with Windows API

```
GetModuleHandleEx(GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS, (LPCTSTR)<SOME_FUNCTION>, &outModule);
```

Is there anything similar or any other method with C++ on a mac??

Thanks,
Abhinay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Core Foundation functions that operate on `CFBundle`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFBundleRef/) to get the bundle reference to the bundle that exports a given **function name**:

```
CFStringRef functionName = CFSTR("someFunctionName");
CFArrayRef allBundles = CFBundleGetAllBundles();
CFIndex i;
CFIndex bundleCount = CFArrayGetCount(allBundles);

for (i = 0; i < bundleCount; i++) {
    CFBundleRef bundle = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allBundles, i);
    void *functionPointer = CFBundleGetFunctionPointerForName(bundle, functionName);
    if (functionPointer != NULL) {
        // bundle points to a bundle that exports functionName
    }
}
```

And since `CFBundleGetDataPointerForName()` returns a data pointer to a given symbol name in a bundle, I believe it can be used for **class names** as well since a class is exported with a symbol name `_OBJC_CLASS_$_<className>`, e.g. `_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSArray`.

As far as I can tell, there’s no function that allows to you to inspect whether a bundle exports a function by specifying the function address.